# Improving an algorithm for defining a matrix

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I am making a program of combinatorics.

There is a step where I give an integer n and I want n positive or zero integers $a_i$ so that $\sum \limits_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

I would like to create a matrix so that each row contains some integers verifying the above condition. I would like this matrix to contain all families of $a_i$.

ex : n=3

0  1  2

0  2  1

1  1  1

1  2  0

.....etc

I first made a naive algorithm : I created the enormous matrix containing every possible combination of [0,$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$] for rows. Then I erase the rows which do not follow the above condition.

The problem is the length of this matrix is about $(n^2)^n$...and my computer can't calculate what I ask him for.

I need a simplier way to obtain the matrix.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your intetegers aren't positive if they include 0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you are interested in  the number of partitions of a set this is the so called Bell number (with a slight modification). Maybe that helps in your search for a good answer. At first glance I did not find a good formula to determine the partitions themselves though...

This was my original approach to this problem: (it's a stream of conscience approach I'm afraid, it's the first time I try and tackle this problem)

I think I have a method, but it's quite hard to explain.
Look at this expression of $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=N$ numbers 1 with N-1 gates between them. 
$$ 1 | 1 | \dots |1 | 1.$$
Every gate has to possible "states": open (O) and closed (C).
Let $N$ be $2$. 
We get this sequence of ones and gates
$$1 | 1$$
The algorithm I propose is to add all numbers which are connected by open gates. In this example you have 2 possible "gate configurations"
$1 O 1$ and $1 C 1$ representing the numbers sequences
(2) and (1,1). Now let us try it for $N=3$ (there will be $2^{3-1}$ gate configurations).

1 O 1 O 1

1 O 1 C 1

1 C 1 O 1

1 C 1 C 1

representing the sequences (3), (2,1) , (1,2), (1,1,1) respectively.

So it boils down to this just walk through the $2^{N-1}$ gate configurations (yeah I know it's still a lot but it's better than $n^n$ ...)
Then all you've got to do is add zeros. There is a time expensive approach that will yield to much answers: just add zeros to every solution you can find and scramble them.  I think that it would be wiser to first subdivide number sequences in equivalent sequences. Of course that means that we have calculated way to many sequences in the first place so back to the drawing board for some optimalisation...

How about this? We are going to rearrange the gate method, look at the length of the possible "sequences for $N=3$, it's$ $1,2,2, 3$ So all you have to do is apply the gate method to the "inner sequences".

My answer is far from perfect, I know, but maybe it helps a little :).

Comment: That's a great idea. The only problem is that I can't see how to implement it. With a bit of work, I should manage to do it. My goal with this program is to calculate the number of possible $(a_i)$ so that $\sum \limits_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i=t_{n-1}$ and $\forall$ r, s $\in [ 0, n-1 ]$, $\sum \limits_{i=r}^{r+s} a_i \ge t_s$ (considering the $(a_i)$ family as periodic). I'm thinking about applying your method to the whole algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't completely clear what you mean by "all families." A recursive algorithm would be as follows: To get all the possibilities for $a_0, \ldots, a_k$ to sum up to $s$, try asigning $s, s - 1, \ldots, 0$ to $a_k$, and (recursively) handle asigning $0, 1, \ldots, s$ to $a_0, \ldots, a_{k - 1}$. To start the whole procedure, you are asking for all ways of summing up to $n (n - 1) / 2$ in $a_0, \ldots, a_{n - 1}$. It is easy to add further conditions, i.e., $a_i$ in increasing order, to this skeleton.